# Combining 2 separate SQL queries

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I am trying to merge 2 separate queries into one. I'am using them for jaspersoft reporting studio. The output of the first query are details about entries in a table between a specified date range. 
The output of the second query contains the some of the amount of output from the first query with it's own parameters. They are working fine seperately.

So I am not even sure if it is possible to combine these in to 1 single query.

query 1:

```
 SELECT
 `alarminfo`.`condition_id`,
 `alarminfo`.`landscape_h`,
 `landscape`.`domain_name`,
 `model`.`model_name`,
 `alarminfo`.`set_time`,
 `alarminfo`.`clear_time` ,
 `alarminfo`.`alarm_key`,
 `alarmtitle`.`title`,
 `alarminfo`.`ack_time`,
 `alarminfo`.`set_troubleticket_id`,
 `alarminfo`.`first_assigned_time`,
 `alarmcondition`.`condition_name`,
 TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,alarminfo.set_time ,alarminfo.clear_time) seconds_to_clear,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,alarminfo.set_time ,'2017-09-01 00:00:00.0') alerttime
 FROM  alarminfo
 INNER JOIN landscape ON (alarminfo.landscape_h=landscape.landscape_h)
 INNER JOIN alarmtitle ON (alarminfo.alarm_title_id=alarmtitle.alarm_title_id)
 INNER JOIN model ON (alarminfo.model_key=model.model_key)
 INNER JOIN alarmcondition on (alarminfo.condition_id=alarmcondition.condition_id)
  where
 ((alarminfo.set_time>='2017-09-01 00:00:00.0' AND alarminfo.set_time<'2017-09-30 23:59:59.0') AND
   (alarminfo.clear_time>='2017-09-01 00:00:00.0' AND alarminfo.clear_time<'2017-09-30 23:59:59.0') AND
   (alarmcondition.condition_name IN ('Critical', 'Major', 'Minor')) AND
   (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,alarminfo.set_time ,alarminfo.ack_time)>60*15)


 )
   order by `alarminfo`.`set_troubleticket_id`DESC , `alarminfo`.`ack_time` , `alarminfo`.`set_time` , `alarminfo`.`landscape_h`, `alarminfo`.`condition_id`
```

Query 2:

```
select
count(*) 'Total alarms',
  sum(case when ack_time is not null then 1 else 0 end) as 'total acknowledged',
  sum(case when (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,alarminfo.set_time ,alarminfo.ack_time)<60*15) then 1 else 0 end) as 'Total acknowledged within 15min',
  sum(case when (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,alarminfo.set_time ,alarminfo.ack_time)>60*15) then 1 else 0 end) as 'Total acknowledged after 15min'
 FROM  alarminfo
 where
 alarminfo.set_time>='2017-09-01 00:00:00.0' AND alarminfo.set_time<'2017-09-30 23:59:59.0'
```

This is how I am trying to merge them together:

```
SELECT
 `alarminfo`.`condition_id`,
 `alarminfo`.`landscape_h`,
 `landscape`.`domain_name`,
 `model`.`model_name`,
 `alarminfo`.`set_time`,
 `alarminfo`.`clear_time` ,
 `alarminfo`.`alarm_key`,
 `alarmtitle`.`title`,
 `alarminfo`.`ack_time`,
 `alarminfo`.`set_troubleticket_id`,
 `alarminfo`.`first_assigned_time`,
 `alarmcondition`.`condition_name`,
 TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,alarminfo.set_time ,alarminfo.clear_time) seconds_to_clear,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,alarminfo.set_time ,'2017-09-01 00:00:00.0') alerttime
 FROM  alarminfo
 INNER JOIN landscape ON (alarminfo.landscape_h=landscape.landscape_h)
 INNER JOIN alarmtitle ON (alarminfo.alarm_title_id=alarmtitle.alarm_title_id)
 INNER JOIN model ON (alarminfo.model_key=model.model_key)
 INNER JOIN alarmcondition on (alarminfo.condition_id=alarmcondition.condition_id)
  where
 ((alarminfo.set_time>='2017-09-01 00:00:00.0' AND alarminfo.set_time<'2017-09-30 23:59:59.0') AND
   (alarminfo.clear_time>='2017-09-01 00:00:00.0' AND alarminfo.clear_time<'2017-09-30 23:59:59.0') AND
   (alarmcondition.condition_name IN ('Critical', 'Major', 'Minor')) AND
   (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,alarminfo.set_time ,alarminfo.ack_time)>60*15)


 )

count(*) 'Total alarms',
  sum(case when ack_time is not null then 1 else 0 end) as 'total acknowledged',
  sum(case when (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,alarminfo.set_time ,alarminfo.ack_time)<60*15) then 1 else 0 end) as 'Total acknowledged within 15min',
  sum(case when (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,alarminfo.set_time ,alarminfo.ack_time)>60*15) then 1 else 0 end) as 'Total acknowledged after 15min'
 FROM  alarminfo
 where
 alarminfo.set_time>='2017-09-01 00:00:00.0' AND alarminfo.set_time<'2017-09-30 23:59:59.0'
)

   order by `alarminfo`.`set_troubleticket_id`DESC , `alarminfo`.`ack_time` , `alarminfo`.`set_time` , `alarminfo`.`landscape_h`, `alarminfo`.`condition_id`
```

This unfortunately is not working. Someone has an idea on how to merge them?

Comment: Please show sample input and expected output for your case: sample output of each query, and what output you want in merged query.

Comment: What are you trying to actually solve in reporting terms?

Comment: first output is the larger query
second is the small query. 

This is just output from a mysql query browser. The query will be used in jaspersoft where I will use only specific data. 

the second is actually a total of certain alarms. I was just wondering how to make these 2 query's go together

[enter image description here][1]


[enter image description here][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjIQM.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG7QJ.png

Answer (score 0):

Use output of first query as input for second query.Since, where clause of second query is already covered in first query So we can omit it.

> select
>      count(*) 'Total alarms',
>        sum(case when ack_time is not null then 1 else 0 end) as 'total acknowledged',
>        sum(case when (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,R.set_time ,R.ack_time)<60*15) then 1 else 0 end) as 'Total acknowledged within 15min',
>        sum(case when (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,R.set_time ,R.ack_time)>60*15) then 1 else 0 end) as 'Total acknowledged after 15min'
>       FROM ( SELECT
>      `alarminfo`.`condition_id`,
>      `alarminfo`.`landscape_h`,
>      `landscape`.`domain_name`,
>      `model`.`model_name`,
>      `alarminfo`.`set_time`,
>      `alarminfo`.`clear_time` ,
>      `alarminfo`.`alarm_key`,
>      `alarmtitle`.`title`,
>      `alarminfo`.`ack_time`,
>      `alarminfo`.`set_troubleticket_id`,
>      `alarminfo`.`first_assigned_time`,
>      `alarmcondition`.`condition_name`,
>      TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,alarminfo.set_time ,alarminfo.clear_time) seconds_to_clear,
>      TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,alarminfo.set_time ,'2017-09-01 00:00:00.0') alerttime
>      FROM  alarminfo
>      INNER JOIN landscape ON (alarminfo.landscape_h=landscape.landscape_h)
>      INNER JOIN alarmtitle ON (alarminfo.alarm_title_id=alarmtitle.alarm_title_id)
>      INNER JOIN model ON (alarminfo.model_key=model.model_key)
>      INNER JOIN alarmcondition on (alarminfo.condition_id=alarmcondition.condition_id)
>      where
>      ((alarminfo.set_time>='2017-09-01 00:00:00.0' AND alarminfo.set_time<'2017-09-30 23:59:59.0') AND
>      (alarminfo.clear_time>='2017-09-01 00:00:00.0' AND alarminfo.clear_time<'2017-09-30 23:59:59.0') AND
>      (alarmcondition.condition_name IN ('Critical', 'Major', 'Minor')) AND
>      (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,alarminfo.set_time ,alarminfo.ack_time)>60*15)
>      )
>      order by `alarminfo`.`set_troubleticket_id`DESC , `alarminfo`.`ack_time` , `alarminfo`.`set_time` , `alarminfo`.`landscape_h`, `alarminfo`.`condition_id`
>      ) as R

Comment: Now I get the error "every derived table must have its own alias"